# Fatal Error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.4 or higher but the current PHP version is 7.3.11

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a Symfony CRUD application.
These are the steps I did:

- Downloaded and installed XAMPP from here with PHP 7.3.11 https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html
- Navigated to `htdocs` with the CLI of Windows.
- Created a symfony project with the command `composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project`
- Opened up my browser (Firefox 70.0.1) and navigate to the URL: `localhost/my_project/public/`

Here I got the error message:

**Fatal Error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.4 or higher but the current PHP version is 7.3.11.**

When I check my php version in the CLI with `php -v` I get the result that I use PHP 7.4.0 (cli).
When I check the php version by clicking the PHPInfo on the dashboard of XAMPP (localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php), the page shows me the php version 7.3.11.

In the created symfony folder is a file called **symfony.lock**. There is an entry called 
`"php": { "version": "7.4" },`. Changing this entry did not solve my problem.

Any ideas how to solve this?
And why I cannot install and test the newest symfony with XAMPP?

Thanks a lot guys!

Musa

Comment: You have two versions of php installed.  The xampp server is using one and the command line is using the other.  The easiest thing to do is to use the builtin [Symfony server](https://symfony.com/download) instead of the xampp apache server.  If you feel you must use the apache server then configure it to use php 7.4.  Which probably means waiting till xampp releases a new version.  Or you can adjust your PATH to use php 7.3 and start over.

Comment: @Cerad: Thanks for your answer. :)

I decide to install the PHP 7.3, change the global variables, and so on. Now it worked with my XAMPP version.

Answer (score 28):

This is thankfully quite easy to fix. You can tell your composer.json to install vendor libraries based on a specific version of PHP.

For instance we have a project currently in migration from PHP5 to PHP7. We cant install the PHP7 only versions of the libraries, so we add this to your composer.json:

```
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "5.3.29"
    }
  },
```

Now you should be able to install. Delete your `composer.lock`, then run `composer install`!

Here's the relevant documentation:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has helped me. I kept getting this error message even after i've executed `composer dump-autoload`. I have two different versions of php7.x running. php7.3 and php7.4. I had to leave php7.3 as the default because a lot of the apps on our server were using it. Applying this fix to my composer.json fixed the problem and now the app is running smoothly.

Answer (score 27):

You should run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: This will fix the autoloader, but packages will still have been installed which might not be compatible with PHP 7.3. It's best to set the platform option as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59452859/157957) so that Composer knows to make sure *everything* works in the selected PHP version.

Answer (score 5):

to whoever ends up coming here for solution this ended up working for me;

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by running

`$ symfony local:php:refresh`

from the project folder, because the output from running `$ php --version` gave me `PHP 7.4.1 (cli)` while `$ symfony php --version` gave me `PHP 7.3.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`.

After the refresh they showed the same versions.

Edit: This required the use of the [symfony-binary](https://symfony.com/cloud/)

Comment: Looks like you have to remove composer.lock (`rm composer.lock`) and then do a `composer update` too

Answer (score 3):

My problem was updating php version with `sudo update-alternatives --config php` didn't update php-cgi.

Symfony CLI was still using the old version of php-cgi:

```
symfony local:php:list
┌─────────┬───────────┬────────────┬─────────┬────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Version │ Directory │  PHP CLI   │ PHP FPM │    PHP CGI     │ Server  │ System? │
├─────────┼───────────┼────────────┼─────────┼────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 7.2.34  │ /usr      │ bin/php7.2 │         │                │ PHP CLI │         │
│ 7.3.23  │ /usr      │ bin/php7.3 │         │ bin/php-cgi7.3 │ PHP CGI │         │
│ 7.4.11  │ /usr      │ bin/php7.4 │         │ bin/php-cgi7.3 │ PHP CGI │ *       │
└─────────┴───────────┴────────────┴─────────┴────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

I solved it by updating php-cgi:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php-cgi
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be caused by the fact you uploaded the file `vendor/autoload.php` generated on another version of php. This is often the case when using CI/CD to build your PHP app.

So the best approach would be to exclude this file from your artifacts instead of running `composer dump-autoload` (which could be the last chance solution).

Answer (score 1):

You can run `composer update` to re-install the vendor library versions that are compatible with your PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same and could fix it by deleting an export path with php 7.2 in my zshrc.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda late to the party but in my case (Apache server on Ubuntu 18.04), apart from uninstalling previous versions of PHP and installing PHP v.7.4, I had to delete `php7.2.conf` and `php7.2.load` from `/etc/apache2/mods-available/` for my Symfony project to register that I am indeed on version 7.4. Apparently these files persisted after I purged all previous PHP versions from my system and installed PHP v.7.4.

Comment: Thank you so much! All the other solutions didn't work for me! Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

This could happen to you if you have 2 different Docker containers running serving the same project. They take turns taking incoming requests. To solve this look for an old zombie Docker containers that uses PHP 7.3.11 and just `docker stop` and `docker rm` them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I never installed any docker containers. I will consider your approach, when I get the same error message again.

Answer (score 0):

Under your app folder, create a text file and type in `7.4`, then rename the file `.php-version` with no name, just the extension. And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

the php folder that the composer installed in and the the apache server such as xampp, wampp, lampp version are should be the similar.

for exmaple if the version of php that composer is installed with is 7.4 or higher, the apache server version such as xampp, wampp, lampp also should be 7.4 or higher

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the Azure WebApp I solved by setting the CGI to the correct version

```
   <handlers>
        <remove name="PHP74_via_FastCGI"/>
        <add name="PHP74_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" modules="FastCgiModule"
             scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files\PHP\v7.4\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

With 2 PHP versions installed, most likely you forgot to change the `etc / hosts` file for the test domain. Or you need to edit the DNS.

```
//file etc/hosts
#old host -forgot to delete
127.0.0.71 demo.symfony.local 
#new host
127.0.0.74 demo.symfony.local
```

I don't know how the XAMPP installer works, (since I usually manually install and configure), but I can assume that most likely when installing a new XAMPP, it changed the paths in the PATH variable (why the console works with version 7.4), and added hosts to the `etc / hosts` file but did not remove the old hosts (so the site works with old version).

In my case, PHP versions are separated by IP.
If you have 2 PHP versions on one IP, then you will have to stop one of them in order to start another or separate the versions by ports. Otherwise, conflict of interest.
example

```
#httpd.conf -Apache settings (Apache folder for PHP 7.3)
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

```
#httpd.conf -Apache settings (Apache folder for PHP 7.4)
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

```
# etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Result: localhost will contact the one who first occupied port 127.0.0.1:80 in the listening queue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help someone like me, the problem was in **symfony.lock**

```
"php": {
    "version": "7.4"
},
```

Simply change this version to match the one needed by composer (7.3 here)

Answer (score -1):

this can easily happen if you have two different versions of php on your local machine. To get around this find the version of php in console that matches what your local server is running.

```
rm composer.lock
/usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer install
```

Composer will then recreate the lock file with the proper version of php.

Answer (score -1):

in  cpanel change php version 7.4 then set it your issue will be solved
https://prnt.sc/20xd1zl

Comment: Please share more details. As the OP uses Windows, I would assume that he is not using cPanel after all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).