# composer.lock created for PHP version 7.4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I realized a project for my internship using Symfony 4.

I decided to go to OVH to host it for my internship supervisor, however once my project is uploaded, I get this error message:

> Fatal Error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.4 or higher
>   but the current PHP version is 7.3.17.

Knowing that the PHP version of OVH at the far end is 7.3, does anyone have a solution to help me?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59141344/fatal-error-composer-lock-was-created-for-php-version-7-4-or-higher-but-the-cur help?

Comment: First you  need to find out if you have declared PHP 7.4 support in composer.json (`"php":"^7.4"`, for example). Then you need to make sure you haven't used any 7.4 only features. E.g. properties type-hinting.

Comment: In particular, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59452859/157957