# Fatal Error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.4 or higher but the current PHP version is 7.1.33

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

At the moment, I'm facing this issue. I've tried everything: deleting composer.lock, then updating composer.json, tried to update PHP version to the highest version, still the same. When I check PHP version in CMD, it shows that my version is 7.4.10, but when I try to open "public" folder on localhost, it shows this "Fatal error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.4 or higher but the current PHP version is 7.1.33.".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.4 or higher but the current PHP version is 7.3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59141344/fatal-error-composer-lock-was-created-for-php-version-7-4-or-higher-but-the-cur)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Looks like your webserver does use a pretty old PHP version

Answer (score -2):

Try to delete symfony.lock and composer.lock then deletr vendor folder and launch command composer install

Comment: Unless you know for a fact that this will solve the problem (which it probably will not based on the question) then this comes under the heading of a guess/comment/suggestion as opposed to a valid answer.  Generate a few actual answers and earn enough rep to be able to post comments.  Tossing out guesses will only get you down voted which is no fun.

Comment: Don't do that, it will change your dependencies - or can you explain why this should be a valid solution?

Comment: Never delete vendor, use require or purge for this...